# Created a key using SSH keygen, can't see the folder using filezilla

Tags: unix, ssh

I created an ssh key using:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

But when I use FileZilla (FTP) to my server, I can't see the `.ssh` folder or files.
I even tried moving the `id_dsa` file to another folder but I still can't see the file.

Is it hidden?

Answer (score 4):

According to your post your server is a *nix machine. Therefore .ssh is a hidden folder. You need to enable your FTP-Client (here Filezilla) to show hidden directories/files. Afterwards the .ssh directory will show up.

Comment: Had a similar problem using FileZilla - it wasn't clear to me at first how to view hidden files. The option to show hidden files (in version 3.5.3) is under the Server menu: "Force showing hidden files". Not under Edit|Settings as I would have expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same account, it should show up.   Unless you're on a windows machine.  There may be an options to show hidden files & directories (in unix, the .ssh is a hidden directory).

Otherwise, you can try using scp to copy your file

`scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa remoteserver.com:~/.ssh/`

Answer (score 0):

IF you are able to login to the remote server but public-key authentication does not work,
it could be because the `.ssh` files are not in the `home` area that you see after you login.

Have you tried looking at the log files on the server?

```
/var/log/messages
# Any, other server specific logging? maybe you need to enable it?
```

I have not used FileZilla first-hand, don't have details.
There must be some way to go verbose and check what is failing on the auth path.

Answer (score 0):

SSH pair key authentication is *very* picky about permissions. I wouldn't try to set up the folders and keys with an FTP application. There are many thorough tutorials about setting up key pairs , for example [here](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/).